# Haskell, function works when using numbers, but not with variables

Tags: variables, haskell, types, literals

I'm using ghci and I'm having a problem with a function for getting the factors of a number.

The code I would like to work is:

```
let factors n = [x | x <- [1..truncate (n/2)], mod n x == 0]
```

It doesn't complain when I then hit enter, but as soon as I try to use it (with 66 in this case) I get this error message:

```
Ambiguous type variable 't0' in the constraints:
  (Integral t0)
    arising from a use of 'factors' at <interactive>:30:1-10
  (Num t0) arising from the literal '66' at <interactive>:30:12-13
  (RealFrac t0)
    arising from a use of 'factors' at <interactive:30:1-10
  Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
  In the expression: factors 66
  In the equation for 'it': it = factors 66
```

The following code works perfectly:

```
let factorsOfSixtySix = [x | x <- [1..truncate (66/2)], mod 66 x == 0]
```

I'm new to haskell, and after looking up types and typeclasses, I'm still not sure what I'm meant to do.

Comment: Guess what would `n/2` return!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `div` for integer division instead:

```
let factors n = [x | x <- [1.. n `div` 2], mod n x == 0]
```

The problem in your code is that `/` requires a `RealFrac` type for `n` while `mod` an `Integral` one. This is fine during definition, but then you can not choose a type which fits both constraints.

Another option could be to truncate `n` before using `mod`, but is more cumbersome. After all, you do not wish to call `factors 6.5`, do you? ;-)

```
let factors n = [x | x <- [1..truncate (n/2)], mod (truncate n) x == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a type annotation on this top-level bind (idiomatic Haskell), you get different, possibly more useful error messages.

```
GHCi> let factors n = [x | x <- [1..truncate (n/2)], mod n x == 0]
GHCi> :t factors
factors :: (Integral t, RealFrac t) => t -> [t]
GHCi> let { factors :: Double -> [Double]; factors n = [x | x <- [1..truncate (n/2)], mod n x == 0]; }

<interactive>:30:64:
    No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of `truncate'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Integral Double)
    In the expression: truncate (n / 2)
    In the expression: [1 .. truncate (n / 2)]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [1 .. truncate (n / 2)]
GHCi> let { factors :: Integer -> [Integer]; factors n = [x | x <- [1..truncate (n/2)], mod n x == 0]; }

<interactive>:31:66:
    No instance for (RealFrac Integer) arising from a use of `truncate'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Integer)
    In the expression: truncate (n / 2)
    In the expression: [1 .. truncate (n / 2)]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [1 .. truncate (n / 2)]

<interactive>:31:77:
    No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of `/'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
    In the first argument of `truncate', namely `(n / 2)'
    In the expression: truncate (n / 2)
    In the expression: [1 .. truncate (n / 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Haskell so please forgive my courage to come up with an answer here but recently i have done this as follows;

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors n = f' ++ [n `div` x | x <- tail f', x /= exc]
            where lim = truncate (sqrt (fromIntegral n))
                  exc = ceiling (sqrt (fromIntegral n))
                  f'  = [x | x <- [1..lim], n `mod` x == 0]
```

I believe it's more efficient. You will notice if you do like;

```
sum (factors 33550336)
```